# How to repair this damp ceiling patch?

Tags: plaster, wallpaper

While repainting my house, I pulled some plaster off the hallway ceiling and ended up with this beauty:

[image: ugly hole in ceiling]

It's about a meter wide. Underneath is a layer of some kind of board, and a damp patch with some mould, which I suppose has caused the plaster to peel. Then a layer of wallpaper, then a thin layer of plaster and finally paint.

This seems complex. Can anyone suggest the best way to repair it? Could I just plaster over? Should I deal with the damp first? The house's outside needs its concrete render redoing which is probably where the damp comes from, but I can't fix that for a month or two; is it a good idea to repair this before doing that?

Comment: The water problem has to be corrected first. If you don't you'll be back at this point again.

Comment: `is it a good idea to repair this before doing that?`  .... are you seriously asking that?

Comment: Yes, I was seriously asking. It seems best to wait until I can fix the underlying problem, but I am worried that leaving this unresolved for a month might cause other problems in turn!